# Azure logic app API http response with excel file download using Postman

Tags: api, sharepoint, postman, azure-logic-apps

Created azure logic app HTTP request it gives response for normal JSON schema However, I want to attach SharePoint excel sheet when I trigger the request from Postman.

1.How to used content type or schema to download the attached file. when postman request sent.

2.is that possible to download when you hit API through logic app

3.Generated HTTP POST URL is working

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, I test it in my side. It seems we do not need to set any value for "Content-Type" in headers of response. Please refer to my logic app below:

[image]

Then when you request the logic app url in postman, please choose "**Send and Download**" instead of "**Send**".

[image]

After that, you can download the file when request the url in postman.

Comment: this is how i have exactly done but the downloaded excel file is empty

Comment: Hi @Sandhya It works fine in my side. Could you please provide more details(or screenshots) of your steps ?

Comment: Fantastic Hury Shen, given wrong in the body working fine.

Comment: Hi  Hury Shen, how to attach two files where one is .xls  another .xlsx in the same logic app?

Comment: Hi @Sandhya According to some test, I'm afraid we can not attach multiple files in the response of logic app request.